# My strstr() returning null even if the string to be found is at the index 0

Tags: c, string

I implemented strstr() myself,the code works fine for all strings but when the string lies in the first index of the string,it returns null.

```
#include<stdio.h>

const char* mystrstr(const char *str1, const char *str2);

int main()
{
 const char *str1="chal bhai nikal";
 const char *str2="c",*result;
 result=mystrstr(str1,str2);
 if(*result!=NULL)
 printf("found at %d location and the value is %s.",*result, str1+*result);
 else
 printf("Value not found");
 getchar();
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}

const char * mystrstr(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
 int i,j,k,len2,count=0;
 char *p;

 for(len2=0;*(s2+len2)!='\0';len2++); //len2 becomes the length of s2
 for(i=0;*(s1+i)!='\0';i++)
 {
  if(*(s1+i)==*s2)
  {
  for(j=i,k=0;*(s2+k)!='\0';j++,k++)
   {
    if(*(s1+j)==*(s2+k))
    count++;
    else count=0;
    if(count==len2)
    {
     p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
     *p = i;
     return p;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

Comment: why are you reimplementing this function? Is this homework?

Comment: Basic debugging questions always apply: What have you tried? What did you expect? What did you actually see?  What specific questions do you have? (otherwise, this is a "plz debugz mah code 4 me" question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't looked at your `mystrstr` function, just `main`.

```
const char *str2="c",*result;
result=mystrstr(str1,str2);
if(*result!=NULL)
printf("found at %d location and the value is %s.",*result, str1+*result);
else
printf("Value not found");
```

`result` is a `const char *`; `*result` is a `const char`.

Are you perhaps mixing `NULL pointer` and `NUL zero-terminator`?

`result` can be `NULL`; `*result` can be `'\0'`

---

Edit: possible solution

When strstr() fails to find the substring it returns NULL. Supposing your mystrstr() works the same way, you do

```
/* result=mystrstr(str1,str2); */
result=NULL;
```

and then

```
if(*result!=NULL) {/* ... */} else {}
```

but `*result` can try to dereference a NULL pointer, which is **NOT** what you want.
You want to test `result` itself

```
if (result != NULL) { /* ... */ } else {}
```

Comment: @fahad: better description now ... still haven't looked at your mystrstr function

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're returning an index in memory pointed to by a `char*` (and in this particular case, the matching index is 0, which your code is interpreting as a NULL when it checks the dereferenced `result`).  If you want `mystrstr()` to have the same behavior as `strstr()`, you should change:

```
if(count==len2)
{
 p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
 *p = i;
 return p;
}
```

to:

```
if(count==len2)
{
  return s1+i;
}
```

so a pointer to the substring location is returned.

`strstr()` doesn't return an index (or a pointer to an index) - it returns a pointer to the character in the string passed as the first parameter where the instance of `str2` is found (if it is found). I assume that your intent is for `mystrstr()` to follow that specification.

So, you'll also need to change the code that checks and deals with the returned value, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Can you please explain the diffrence between pointer to index and pointer to character as you said?

Answer (score 0):

What the above person said was ok. Because in his way, **you don't need to declare a pointer to char `p` and use  `malloc` to allocate memory for returning  pointer to index**. It can simplify your code.

But you need to change your `main` function accordingly.

```
const char* mystrstr(const char *str1, const char *str2);

int main()
{
    const char *str1 = "chal bhai nikal";
    const char *str2 = "bh", *result;

    result = mystrstr(str1, str2);
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        printf("found at %d location and the value is %s.\n", result - str1, result);
    }
    else
        printf("Value not found");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```